# How can I get a specific snapshot of a playlist from the Spotify Web API?

Tags: api, spotify

According to the [Spotify docs](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/working-with-playlists/#version-control-and-snapshots), updates to a playlist result in a new revision, having its own snapshot_id.

In the [docs for getting a playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlist/) and [for getting a playlists tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlists-tracks/), though, there is no documentation for how to specify a snapshot.

Furthermore, there doesn't seem to be a way to discover past snapshots.

So, is there a (perhaps undocumented) way to discover existing snapshot_ids, and view a playlist as it once was given a snapshot_id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very good question and it makes me curious of what you're building! I work on the Web API, and I can tell you that it isn't supported. The reason the Web API uses snapshots is to support concurrent changes - e.g. if you retrieve a playlist and want to remove one of its tracks, you want to be sure that the correct track is removed even though a change has occurred since you retrieved it.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I have a bad habit of forgetting to save songs I like that show up in my Discover Weekly, so I was thinking it would be cool to build a tool to keep an archive of some sort. Being able to look back in time would have taken care of basically all the work though :/

Comment: That's a good use case. There are however no plans on including this in the API. Have a look at this [IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/313128-archive-spotify-discover-weekly-tracks), I use it myself and it satisfies your case.

Comment: I wanted to build a quick tool to show how a user's music tastes change over time; the ability to see previous snapshots of a playlist would be necessary for this. Would be interested in finding out if this is ever decided to be added to the API.

Comment: I had the same idea, and yes it looks like it isn't possible to retrieve old snapshot_ids for playlists (so no Discover Weekly history!)